# database lock issue in HTC Desire

Tags: android, database, concurrency, transactions, locking

In my application one service is getting data from server and inserting it to `table A`.

If I go to particular UI, I need to list data from another `table B` if background 
      operation is doing it will generate database locked exception. I got two database 
       operation done in parallel each on two different table.

It is working fine in samsung gt15801. But htc desire it will generate database locked 
       error.

> HTC desire - insertion process takes 91 seconds.
>
> Samsung gt15801 - insertion process takes 21 seconds.

Comment: Using [this](http://notes.theorbis.net/2010/02/batch-insert-to-sqlite-on-android.html) method takes less time for insertion now it takes only 3 seconds instead of 91 seconds

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to use one *SqliteDatabaseHelper* and make it *single instance.* After that **don't close the SqliteDatabase instance after complete your operations**.

You can implement lock on database for that see this

http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html

When you start a database operation which has many concurrent operation then you have to use

```
database.beginTransaction(); /* for start transaction */
```

and after completing operation on database you can use

```
database.setTransactionSuccessful();    
database.endTransaction();
```

But if you give error in between transaction then don't set `database.setTransactionSuccessful();` so that the transaction will be rollback.

Also you can check at the time of error whether currently the database is in transaction or not by `database.inTransaction();` if it return true then you are in transaction else you are not in transaction

<s>Also You can check for whether current database has locked or not by calling</s>

```
database.isDbLockedByCurrentThread();
database.isDbLockedByOtherThreads();
```

this will return Boolean.

Also you can set whether you want to lock your database if multiple threads are trying to read and write your database at the same time by

```
database.setLockingEnabled(boolean);
```

Above deleted methods are deprecated so please do not use.

Comment: thanks for the reply.so if I want to do concurrent operation on database then I need to do LOCK right? thanks.

Comment: do not use `isDbLockedByOtherThreads()` as it will always return false. There is no longer concept of database lock.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#isDbLockedByOtherThreads()