# Android Database Transaction

Tags: android, sqlite, transactions

I have created a database. I want to do the Transaction. `SaveCustomer()` contains more than one statement to insert records into `Customer, CustomerControl, Profile, Payment` table at that time.

When a user calls  `SaveCustomer()` method then that data will go to these 4 tables.so How can I do the transaction? If one table inserts failed then need to roll back everything. For example, when 3rd table inserts the record I got an error, then need to roll back previous two table's insert records also.

See my code:

```
public void saveCustomer(){
    DBAdapter dbAdapter = DBAdapter.getDBAdapterInstance(RetailerOrderKeyActivity.this);
    dbAdapter.openDataBase();
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put("CustomerName",customer.getName());
    initialValues.put("Address",customer.getAddress());
    initialValues.put("CustomerPID",strPID);
    initialValues.put("Date",strDateOnly);
    long n = dbAdapter.insertRecordsInDB("Customer", null, initialValues);

}
```

Likewise  other statement also there.

DBAdpter code is :

```
public long insertRecordsInDB(String tableName, String nullColumnHack,ContentValues initialValues) {
    long n =-1;
    try {
        myDataBase.beginTransaction();
        n = myDataBase.insert(tableName, nullColumnHack, initialValues);

        myDataBase.endTransaction();
        myDataBase.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // how to do the rollback 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return n;
}
```

This is the full code:

```
public class DBAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.my.controller/databases/";
    private static final String DB_NAME = "customer";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context myContext;
    private static DBAdapter mDBConnection;


    private DBAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
        DB_PATH = "/data/data/"
                + context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                + "/databases/";
        // The Android's default system path of your application database is
        // "/data/data/mypackagename/databases/"
    }


    public static synchronized DBAdapter getDBAdapterInstance(Context context) {
        if (mDBConnection == null) {
            mDBConnection = new DBAdapter(context);
        }
        return mDBConnection;
    }


    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (dbExist) {
            // do nothing - database already exist
        } else {
            // By calling following method 
            // 1) an empty database will be created into the default system path of your application 
            // 2) than we overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }


    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            // database does't exist yet.
        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }


    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);  
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
            // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    /**
     * Open the database
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);      
    }


    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    /**
     * Call on creating data base for example for creating tables at run time
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE WMPalmUploadControl ADD Testing int");

    }

    public void upgradeDb(){
        onUpgrade(myDataBase, 1, 2);
    }

    public Cursor selectRecordsFromDB(String tableName, String[] tableColumns,
            String whereClase, String whereArgs[], String groupBy,
            String having, String orderBy) {
        return myDataBase.query(tableName, tableColumns, whereClase, whereArgs,
                groupBy, having, orderBy);
    }


    public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> selectRecordsFromDBList(String tableName, String[] tableColumns,
            String whereClase, String whereArgs[], String groupBy,
            String having, String orderBy) {        

        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> retList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
          ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
          Cursor cursor = myDataBase.query(tableName, tableColumns, whereClase, whereArgs,
                    groupBy, having, orderBy);        
          if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
             do {
                 list = new ArrayList<String>();
                 for(int i=0; i<cursor.getColumnCount(); i++){                   
                     list.add( cursor.getString(i) );
                 }   
                 retList.add(list);
             } while (cursor.moveToNext());
          }
          if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
             cursor.close();
          }
          return retList;

    }   


    public long insertRecordsInDB(String tableName, String nullColumnHack,ContentValues initialValues) {
        long n =-1;
        try {
            myDataBase.beginTransaction();
            n = myDataBase.insert(tableName, nullColumnHack, initialValues);

            myDataBase.endTransaction();
            myDataBase.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // how to do the rollback 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return n;
    }


    public boolean updateRecordInDB(String tableName,
            ContentValues initialValues, String whereClause, String whereArgs[]) {
        return myDataBase.update(tableName, initialValues, whereClause,
                whereArgs) > 0;             
    }

    public int updateRecordsInDB(String tableName,
            ContentValues initialValues, String whereClause, String whereArgs[]) {
        return myDataBase.update(tableName, initialValues, whereClause, whereArgs);     
    }


    public int deleteRecordInDB(String tableName, String whereClause,
            String[] whereArgs) {
        return myDataBase.delete(tableName, whereClause, whereArgs);
    }


    public Cursor selectRecordsFromDB(String query, String[] selectionArgs) {
        return myDataBase.rawQuery(query, selectionArgs);       
    }


    public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> selectRecordsFromDBList(String query, String[] selectionArgs) {       
          ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> retList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
          ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
          Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(query, selectionArgs);            
          if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
             do {
                 list = new ArrayList<String>();
                 for(int i=0; i<cursor.getColumnCount(); i++){                   
                     list.add( cursor.getString(i) );
                 }   
                 retList.add(list);
             } while (cursor.moveToNext());
          }
          if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
             cursor.close();
          }
          return retList;
       }

}
```

[database lock issue in HTC Desire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951506/database-lock-problem-in-htc-desire/6955195#6955195).

I want to roll back if there any issues occurred when inserting the table data.

Please help me

Thanks.

I looked this same related question :

Answer (score 285):

Actually you are doing wrong.
You have to set begin transaction if you have multiple records to insert into database or
if you have to rollback data from other table if there is a problem in inserting data in one of the database table.

For example

You have two tables

1. A
2. B

Now you want to insert data in these two tables but you will have to rollback transaction if you will get any error at the time of inserting data in the tables.

Now you have successfully insert data in table A and now you are trying to insert data in the table B.Now if you get error at the time of inserting data in the table B then you have to delete relevant data from table A that means you have to rollback the transaction.

**How you can use database transaction in Android**

1. If you want to start the transaction there is a method [`beginTransaction()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction%28%29)
2. If you want to commit the transaction there is a method [`setTransactionSuccessful()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#setTransactionSuccessful%28%29) which will commit the values in the database
3. If you had start the transaction you need to close the transaction so there is a method [`endTransaction()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#endTransaction%28%29) which will end your database transaction

Now there are two main points

1. If you want to set transaction successful you need to write [`setTransactionSuccessful()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#setTransactionSuccessful%28%29) and then [`endTransaction()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#endTransaction%28%29) after [`beginTransaction()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction%28%29)
2. If you want to rollback your transaction then you need to [`endTransaction()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#endTransaction%28%29) without committing the transaction by [`setTransactionSuccessful()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#setTransactionSuccessful%28%29).

You can get detailed information about the SQLite database transaction from [here](http://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html)

**In your case**

You can call your `saveCustomer()` function in try and catch blocks

```
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    saveCustomer();
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} catch {
    //Error in between database transaction 
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: You should add `endTransaction` in your finally, not in your try block.

Comment: @VansFannel you are right finally is the best place to close the database transaction. thanks for make it better.

Answer (score 25):

you should add `endTransaction` in your `finally`, not in your try block

```
 finally {
     myDataBase.endTransaction();
   }
```

> The changes will be rolled back if any transaction is ended without
>   being marked as clean  (by calling setTransactionSuccessful).
>   Otherwise they will be committed.

Comment: Thanks for the information. In my 'SaveCustomer()` i am going to call ' long n = dbAdapter.insertRecordsInDB("Customer", null, initialValues);' in 4 time with different records. Will it rollback everything, if there any erro occur even in the middle table.I have 4 table.Need to add records in 4 table with different records.?

Answer (score 19):

Insert Record Using Transaction, This is very fast

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?)";
db.beginTransaction();

SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement(sql);
for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
    stmt.bindString(1, values.get(i).col1);
    stmt.bindString(2, values.get(i).col2);
    stmt.execute();
    stmt.clearBindings();
}

db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();
```