# How action insert transaction of android calllog?

Tags: android, insert, transactions, calllog

If insert 100 calllog failed,How rollback ? Is  Android  provide A similar approach ?

```
ArrayList<ContentValues> lstValues = new ArrayList<ContentValues>();
        for(SmsItem smsItem : data){
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
            long threadId = getOrCreateThreadId(mContext, new String[] {smsItem.address});
            values.put(THREAD_ID, threadId);
            values.put(ADDRESS, smsItem.address);
            values.put(DATE, smsItem.date*1000L);
            values.put(TYPE, smsItem.tpye);
            values.put(BODY, smsItem.body);
            values.put(READ,smsItem.read );
            lstValues.add(values);
        } 
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(SMS_URI);

        int count = mContext.getContentResolver().bulkInsert(uri,
                lstValues.toArray(new ContentValues[lstValues
                                                    .size()]) );//if here is failed,how rollback?
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to perform database operation with transaction. Using Transaction, you can perform large number of insertion efficiently and it can rollback if in case of any error.

For more detail check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8163179/685240).