# Android app taking much time to load data from sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am making an android app which requires 1200 records to insert and then fetch. I am using sqlite as back end. Everything is working fine but app takes lot of time to load the data at very first time for new installation. I am using SQLiteOpenHelper class to insert data. Please suggest ways to reduce the time to load the data at very first time.

EDIT :
I resolved my problem:) Here is how?
My app was taking much time because, I was inserting all the 1200 records at a time. Now i changed my code such that it should insert only required data one at a time so it saved my lot of time.

Comment: Why don't you provide a **pre-filled database**?

Comment: There's no simple answer.  SQLite is not very well optimised for large amounts of data.  Your best bet is to display a progress indicator showing to the user the state of play.

Answer (score 1):

Use transactions as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147440/android-database-transaction) and make sure that you are only creating one connection to the SQL database for the transaction(s)

There should be a significant speed increase

Comment: Hi Thank you for your response! I think my app is taking time bacause I am inserting huge records a the same time in fact i dont need all that records at one time. Here is the requirement,