# Efficient way to handle big nested for loops to insert in db in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a huge data which i need to insert in sqlite database.

```
public synchronized void insert(ResponseModel[] response) {

    for (int i = 0; i < response.length; i++) { // Here response length is 100
        for (int j = 0; j < response[i].getPings().size(); j++) { // Here per response, ping size is around 300
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            if (response[i].getPings().get(j).getId() != null)
                cv.put(Constants.ID, response[i].getPings().get(j).getId().toString().trim());
            // More insertion code goes here
        }
    }
}
```

Now in this situation, the application takes too much time. The app doesn't hangs because it happens in a background thread.
Is there any way to efficiently handle this huge looping?

Comment: At least you can move 'ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();' outside the loops and reuse it.

Comment: Use a transaction. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147440/android-database-transaction

Comment: How will a transaction help me in this huge loop ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html

Comment: @RahulGupta, may I ask you to mark the answer as correct if it was useful for you and answers your question :)

Comment: @RahulGupta were you able to overcome this challenge? you have any hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Android SQLite API does not support bulk insertion. Although you can optimize the execution time by using a single transaction. By default Android uses a separate transaction for each `insert()` call. So in your scenario you will have 30000 transactions. Beginning and committing transactions is a time consuming operation. So you can use a single transaction for all the insertions:

```
try{
  db.beginTransaction();

  for (int i = 0; i < response.length; i++) { // Here response length is 100
    for (int j = 0; j < response[i].getPings().size(); j++) { // Here per response, ping size is around 300
      ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
      if (response[i].getPings().get(j).getId() != null) {
        cv.put(Constants.ID, response[i].getPings().get(j).getId().toString().trim());
      }
      // More insertion code goes here
    }
  }

  db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} catch (SQLException e) {
  // Handle the exception...
} finally {
  db.endTranscation();
}
```